Proving that the parallel translation map between tangent spaces at points on a curve is an isomorphism
I'm trying to figure out a proof of this. My understanding is as follows:
Given a curve $\gamma$ on a smooth manifold $M$, a point $p$ on $\gamma$ (or equivalently a parameter value $t_0$ where $\gamma(t_0)=p$), and a vector $v\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$  - there exists a unique parallel vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(\gamma)$ such that $X(\gamma(t_0))=v$.
A parallel translation map corresponding to this curve is $\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}$ is defined as follows: Corresponding to $\gamma$, $t_0$ and $v\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$, let $X$ be the unique parallel vector field as in the above theorem. Then $\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v)=X(\gamma(t_1))$.
Here's my attempt at the isomorphism proof.
Injective: Let $v,w\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$ ($v\neq w$) such that $\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v)=\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(w)$. Corresponding to $(\gamma,t_0,v)$ and $(\gamma,t_0,w)$, there would exist different parallel vector fields $X$ and $Y$ respectively s.t. $X(\gamma(t_0))=v$ and $Y(\gamma(t_0))=w$ (if the fields were the same, then we'd have $v=w$). But due to $\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v)=\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(w)$, we have $v'\equiv X(\gamma(t_1))=Y(\gamma(t_1))\equiv w'$. But now we can use this logic in reverse: corresponding to $(\gamma,t_1,v')$ and $(\gamma,t_1,w')$, we have the same unique vector field parallel along $\gamma$ - say $Z$ - such that $Z(\gamma(t_1))=v'$. But even $X$ is a parallel vector field such that $X(\gamma(t_1))=v'$, and since the vector field is supposed to be unique, $Z=X$. And by the same logic, $Z=Y\implies X=Y$, contradicting $v\neq w$.
Surjective: Let $v'\in T_{\gamma(t_1)}M$. Let $X$ be the unique parallel vector field corresponding to $(\gamma,t_1,v')$ and let $X(\gamma(t_0))=v$. Corresponding to $(\gamma,t_0,v)$ then, $X$ is the unique vector field parallel along $\gamma$. So by definition $\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v)=X(\gamma(t_1))=v'$.
Linearity: Let $v,w\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$. Corresponding to $(\gamma,t_0,v)$ and $(\gamma,t_0,w)$, there would exist different parallel vector fields $X$ and $Y$ respectively s.t. $X(\gamma(t_0))=v$ and $Y(\gamma(t_0))=w$. Also $v+cw=X(\gamma(t_0))+cY(\gamma(t_0))=(X+cY)(\gamma(t_0))$. $X+cY$ is a parallel field along $\gamma$ since $\frac{\nabla}{dt}(X+cY)=\frac{\nabla}{dt}(X)+c\frac{\nabla}{dt}(Y)=0$, hence it's the unique parallel vector field corresponding to the triplet $(\gamma,t_0,v+cw)$. Then
$$\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v+cw)=(X+cY)(\gamma(t_1))=X(\gamma(t_1))+cY(\gamma(t_1))=\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(v)+c\psi^{\gamma}_{t_0,t_1}(w)$$

Does the above proof seem fine or are there any loopholes I may have missed?

There is more to being an isomorphism than being bijective.

@TedShifrin: Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I forgot to add that part. I've added Linearity to the proof as well. Does the proof seem all good now, or any other issues?

Is there any particular part of the proof that you are unsure about? Proof verification questions typically require some clarification of specific points in the proof

You can show a map is an isomorphism by exhibiting an inverse — in this case you can find one using the same curve in reverse
